# CDATA[Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: message Access to the port 'COM10' is denied./ (anotrher error ''communication (port) fault''

Tags: windows-7, serial-port, usb, port

I have a software which is on the retail machine (self check out) installed:

In the device manager, I did not receive any error like, some device is unplugged.

The functionality of the application is this:

Each device of the payment station coin recycler, note acceptor, note distributor are installed on serial ports, and USB ports, these devices send information to the application thru the ports and com:

1. These payment devices are installed with no issues, but after some time I found this error in event viewer (windows7) :
   Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: Coins device is not initialized
   ErrorCode: Failure
   ErrorCodeExtended: 0
   and
   Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: Notes acceptor returned message Access to the port 'COM10' is denied.
   ErrorCode: Failure

Note that in the device manager is nothing unplugged and also devices are in the normal mode, no error identified.

Can somebody please explain why, I receive the above errors, what can I improve?

I need to create a new driver to check the communication of the ports, to close and open the ports.(and if yes please advise how ).

What should I check per total to not receive these errors anymore?
thank you.

Comment: It means another software program is holding that port open. Check your Task Manager and make sure another copy of the program isn't already running. Sometimes if software is not written correctly, it could leave the port open when you close it. The only way to fix that is to reboot the machine.

Comment: Thank you Simon , i checek in cmd netstat and in task manager after pid , and no other device is connected on com 10 . Can be from the software is not written corectly. So what do you suggest ? To create a new driver to check the ports?, the error can be generated by the usb actual driver ?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the OS and trying the software after a reboot?  If the port was being held open by something, rebooting will release it.

Comment: Yes, i rebooted . Thank you, it, solved for the moment , but i want to know if is driver fault.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with drivers.  It seems the program did not release the com port after the last time it was run.  Unfortunately, Serial Ports in Windows can't be released unless whoever has the port open, closes the port.  Rebooting is the only way to release it.

Comment: I think I found the solution for fixing this com 10 is denied.
I made a workaround and I figure out how to fix this problem.
1. Pos net 1.2 (repair, or reinstall).
2. Change the USB cable for the hardware device.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Windows version is Embedded (special for retail created)